# Certificates for SSL-enabled embedded systems

Tags: ssl, embedded, https, certificate

I have an embedded system that I expect to be in use for the next 15 years or so, and it has an https-based administration console.  From what I understand:

- If I have a self-signed certificate, web browsers will complain.
- If I have a CA-signed certificate, it will expire fairly soon over the lifetime of the product, and web browsers will complain.

Is there any way to have a long-life certificate so browsers won't complain, or is it necessary to release new firmware every time the certificate expires over the life of the product?  Or provide a way for the users to load a new certificate?

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation at the moment; i.e. developing a mass-produced embedded system that has an SSL-enabled web server for the purpose of remote administration by a small group of end users only. I'm currently researching into whether (and how) CA-signed certificates could be deployed (which is inhrently difficult considering the CA needs to know the domain of the device upfront), or to use self-signed. What solution did you use in the end? Did you follow Paul McMillan's suggestions regarding an update mechanism, and using a uniqe self-signed certificate for each device?

Comment: @Trevor:  I shipped with a self-signed cert and provided a way for the user to upload their own private key + cert.  Realistically I doubt any customer has ever uploaded their own cert, but it made me feel better at least.

Comment: Thanks for responding so soon. Do you mind if I also ask what kind of mechanism and format you chose for uploading the key and certificate? Is it for instance via a PC / USB update tool, and is the key and certificate itself basically transferred as a chunk of binary (e.g. PEM format) that's just burned into flash?

Comment: And, presumably each device ships with a unique self-signed certificate, perhaps generated internally at first boot-up using a unique generated key?

Comment: @Trevor:  I required that the user upload a file that contained the pkey and cert through the web interface.  After error checking it as much as I could, I then wrote it to flash where it'd take effect on the next power cycle.  I had a file system in flash so it was easy.  You should generate the cert whenever it doesn't exist and that takes care of first-time boot and also flash corruption.

Comment: Thanks again, indiv. Just a couple of further clarifications, if that's okay: (1) Presumably your self-signed 'factory' certificate would have a common name (CN) or SAN that most likely won't match the IP or DNS that the user is accessing the device from. Presumably your users just have to accept this? (I understand that some browsers may not allow an exception for a mismatched CN or SAN.) Secondly, are all individual devices given a different key pair and certificate, perhaps using an automated production line arrangement using OpenSSL running on a PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be one of the rare cases where a self-signed certificate is the correct approach. How many people will need to administer the box? I would think few, and part of the deployment of the box would be to have the certificate installed into the truststore of the administrator's browser.

Comment: You're right for my specific device that only a couple specialized people will ever admin the box or log in via https to monitor it.  We already ship with self-signed certs, but I wasn't sure what others do.

Answer (score 2):

Geotrust issues certs for up to 6 years.

I would probably build a firmware update mechanism in anyway in case your issuer (or someone along the line) is compromised and gets added to the Certificate Revocation List.

Is your device expected to be connected to the internet? Building a re-issue process so that it can get a new, trusted cert every few years via the network shouldn't be too hard.

If your security model would allow you to use a self-signed cert, have you considered why you are encrypting the communication at all? A non-trusted cert (and teaching users to ignore the warning) is as bad (or worse) than no encryption at all in many cases.

As an aside, I really hope you're not planning on rolling out the exact same cert to every device you construct. If so, and you have a download process that makes the cert available to the general public via firmware updates, you're back to square 1 of having communications easily spoofed.